# HTML "area" combined with a "<span>" does work in Chrome but not Mozilla

Tags: html, google-chrome, mozilla, shapes, area

I use following code for displaying three simple rollover images over one main background image. The code works absolutely fine with Chrome, but unluckily not with Mozilla! I hope, somebody might have an idea to improve my lines! Thank you already very much!

```
<img src="business.png" alt="Kart" usemap="#Kart" border="1" style="border-color:#FFFFFF" height="306" width="800">


<map name="Kart">
<a class="info1" href="index4.htm"> <area shape="rect" coords="278,152,289,164"> <span><img src="1.png" width="265" height="116" border="0" style="border-color:#FFFFFF"></span></a>
<a class="info2" href="index4.htm"> <area shape="rect" coords="292,175,303,187"> <span><img src="2.png" width="265" height="93" border="0" style="border-color:#FFFFFF"></span></a>
<a class="info3" href="index4.htm"> <area shape="rect" coords="289,198,300,210"> <span><img src="3.png" width="265" height="75" border="0" style="border-color:#FFFFFF"></span></a>
</map>
```

Comment: A fiddle would be great. And (off-topic) `border` attribute is obsolete, use CSS instead.

Comment: I uploaded a simple test version right here: http://mariaschaepers.bugs3.com/ 
Well, rolling over the arrows should display a simple graphic overlay... and as you can see that's working with Chrome fine - but unluckily there are also some other browsers out there! ;)